# Session_start(); on all pages, bad practice?

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I was wondering if there is a good practice or maby bad practice to add `session_start();`
on all pages even if not needed on +50 pages?

There can be a case where i have ~100 HTML pages and are including headers,footers and sidebars or even footer. So on maby 50 pages there are needed to use `session_start();` and there is only one header .php page which is included on all those pages. so my question is
that there should't be looked as a bad practice?

Comment: You can auto-start the session via a flag in php.ini

Comment: Yes, that's bad; it will block other requests with the session cookie.

Comment: SLaks could you explain a little? aren't session created to individual connections and are unique ? maby i didn't understand

Comment: This is an 'it so depends' situation. It isn't really about number of pages but about which function a user is using and whether that function needs the session. Example, a shopping cart. Most likely needs the session each time? If they have logged into the site then likely session is needed? Anytime a 'data entry' HTML Form is used then the session is required for: CSRF code, 'Captcha code' and maybe, already processed forms' list.  More things to debug and more to go wrong when maintaining the code?